# Gradient effect on text and images

Tags: css

How to create a gradient effect for content on a page like the one on this [website](https://loop.ableton.com/participants/). There is a background image and the text and images showing the color of the background image which gives a gradient effect. How can I create a similar effect (non-static gradient effect)?

[image: text-and-imgs-gradient-effect]

Also is it all CSS or is there any Javascript library that can achieve the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Has two `div` containers positioned over each other. One with a background and the other contains text and images with the css property `mix-blend-mode` set to `screen`

The div with the background should have `position: absolute;` and full `width` and `height`

```
mix-blend-mode: screen;
```

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedosama/q1cxnu82/1/) to demonstrate.

`mix-blend-mode` is not supported by IE or Opera. Read more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/mix-blend-mode/).

Comment: Thanks, your solution was the non-static gradient effect I was looking for. What is in your opinion the best way to support IE and Opera too? Setting a color:black rule on white background for example, in order to make the content still coherent and readable?

Comment: I have updated the fork. Added `position: absolute;` to support IE and Opera. The color is already set to black so when the `mix-blend-mode` is not supported. It will be black text on white background. http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedosama/q1cxnu82/3/

Comment: One thing I noticed in your fiddle is that if you add more content (i.e. two blocks of lorem ipsum text) they are not visible scrolling the page after the viewport height. The content gets truncated and there's only white background.

Comment: Because of the 100% height value on the first div. It is the size of the result part in `jsfiddle`. You can set `min-height` value or set pixel value to height.

Answer (score 1):

For `Text`, you can read the link below with demonstration:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-text-gradient

---

For `Image`, you can do it by adding a filter on the image:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

What filter did they used in the website?

```
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) contrast(1.5) drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px white);
filter: grayscale(100%) contrast(1.5) drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px white);
```